# Javascript in browser bar vs in content script - 'die' doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run a javascript command in a content script using Personalized-Web (a Chrome extension).  I'm new to javascript & jquery, but I've found that entering this code:

```
javascript:jQuery("div.photo-container").die();
```

into my browser bar on a particular page achieves the desired result: it undoes a `.live` call performed in one of the page's javascripts.

However, if I include that same code or `$("div.photo-container").die();` in a content script, it does not work.  I've also attempted including this script tag in the page context:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("div.photo-container").die();
</script>
```

and chrome claims that `$` or `jQuery` are not defined.  However, the page's own javascripts don't `include` or refer to the jQuery source at any point, as far as I can tell.

So, what's the difference between the browser bar, the content script, and the in-page `<script>` tag?  How can I use one of the 'automatic' methods (i.e., not paste it into the browser bar)?

Comment: jQuery must have been loaded at some point for the first example to work. Are you sure there are no other scripts on the page, not even at the end of `<body>`?

Comment: @PPvG - there are many scripts scattered throughout the page.  I guess I should have hunted through them to find if/where jQuery was loaded?

Comment: Nope, sorry, I'd read over your first line. Look at [Mohammed's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8796140/990877) and read the documentation for [Chrome's Content Scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inject that script tag into the page, it should work. For example:

```
// Runs in the context of the webpage.
var injectScript = function() {
  $("div.photo-container").die();
}

// Runs in the context of the content script. We basically just append the DOM
// with the injected script and execute it so it will run.
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.appendChild(document.createTextNode('(' + injectScript + ')();'));
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

The above should work assuming your page has defined the $. If the $ doesn't exist, that means jQuery didn't load yet. Make sure your manifest has `document_end` defined as well.

```
...
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://www.rim.com/*"],
    "js": ["content_script.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }
],
...
```

If that doesn't work then Sometimes depending on the website, it is good to lazy load or smart load till the content (script) gets loaded because the webdesigner is asynchronously loading the scripts or content. In that case, do some research to see how jquery is being loaded. For example, do a timer with `setTimeout` or DOM events to figure out when it is time to run your injection. I do that many times on difficult websites such as Google+ Extensions.

Comment: Thanks.  Your solution is exactly what I was looking for.  However,  I now get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'die' of null`.  It works (the `live` function `die`d as it should have), but there's still this error.  Not a big deal, I just want to make sure I don't break anything.

Comment: I don't know what `die()` is in that regard, try to `console.log($('div.photo-container'))` and see if it prints it out